# File is not showing up in NFT storage on IPFS

Tags: node.js, express, metadata, ipfs, nft

I uploaded file to NFT Storage
I can see file list in https://nft.storage/files/ but if I clicked CID links, I get error `ipfs cat /ipfs/bafyreiayui2us6fpowl42vqwmjrntpewhqpfkbgcak6pt4gkpz55z2o3se/: unknown node type`

My code is as below

```
    const { NFTStorage, File } = require('nft.storage')
    const apiKey ='eyJ........CJ9'
    const client = new NFTStorage({ token: apiKey })

    const metadata = await client.store({
       name: artworkName,
       description: description,
       artistName: artistName,
       image: new File(data, fileName, { type: artfile.mimetype }),
    })
    console.log(metadata.url)
```

I can see metadata.json and file on NFT Storage
[nft storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbZ1p.png)

I think, there is an issue for file size.

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

Your metadata at https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafyreiayui2us6fpowl42vqwmjrntpewhqpfkbgcak6pt4gkpz55z2o3se/metadata.json is:

```
{
  "name": "PrettyDog",
  "description": "This is my first artwork avatar",
  "artistName": "Mark Petru ",
  "image": "ipfs://bafybeig6sxdg4uggvnan6vxvshp7spm7kemmyqxnysyu3d5m57grefzhrq/test.jpg"
}
```

The image is then:
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeig6sxdg4uggvnan6vxvshp7spm7kemmyqxnysyu3d5m57grefzhrq/test.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```bash
ipfs cat <cid>/metadata.json
```

and from the JSON you will find a link to your image.